# Inject text dynamically to facebook's share dialog via content-script - javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, dialog, content-script

- my app is a chrome extension
- I have a content-script injected to Facebook share pop-up.
  I successfully manage to add text to the input via DOM manipulation,
  but when I click share, it clears the input and then share the link.. any idea why?

Comment: Please read the [FAQ], especially ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit this question.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice for FB share is via Open Graph, http://ogp.me/

```
    <!-- Facebook Open Graph Meta Tags -->
    <meta property="og:title" content="OG title" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://domain.com" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://domain.com/fb-image.png" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="OG description" />
```

You can also try FB sharer, but keep in mind that it's deprecated and not advised to use.

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]={title}&p[summary]={text}&p[url]={url}&p[images][0]={image}">fb share</a>
```